# Getting values from csv file in python, large dataset

Tags: python, csv, dataset, data-science

I have a csv file with 500 companies stock values for 5 years (2013-2017). The columns I have are: date, open, high, low, close, volume and name. I would like to be able to compare these companies, to see which 20 of them are the best. I was thinking about just using the mean, but since the stocks value of the first data collected (jan 2013) are different (some starts of at 30 usd, and others at 130 usd), it's hard to really compare which ones that has been the best during these 5 years. I would therefore want to have the values of the first date of every company as the zero-point. Basically I want to subtract the close value from the first date to the rest of the datas collected.

My problem is that, firstly, I have a hard time getting to the first dates close value. Somehow I want to write somthing like "data.loc(data['close']).iloc(0)". But since it's a dataframe I can't find a value of a row, nor iterate through the dataframe.

Secondly, I'm not sure how I can differentiate between the companies. I want to do the procedure with the zero-point for every of these 500 companies, so somehow I need to know when to start over.

The code I have now is

```
def main():

data = pd.read_csv('./all_stocks_5yr.csv', usecols = ['date', 'close', 'Name'])
comp_name = sorted(set(data.Name))
number_of = comp_name.__len__()

comp_mean = []
for i in comp_name:
    frames = data.loc[data['Name'] == i]
    comp_mean.append([i, frames['close'].mean()])

print(comp_mean)
```

But this will only give me the mean, without using the zero-point

Another idea I had was to just compare the closing price from first value (January 1, 2013) with the price from the last value (December 31, 2017) to see how much the stock has increased/decreased, what I'm not sure about here is how I will reach the close values from these dates, for every single of the 500 companies.

Do you have any recommendations for any of the methods?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How big is this file? It might be possible to load it into memory, into separate data structures for each company. Then you can iterate the data for each one in order based on the date/it's position in this data structure. One thing to note is that the flat price change is maybe not as helpful for your analysis as the relative price change. IE, two different stocks might raise in price by 5 dollars over this period of time, but if a stock went from 1 dollor to 6 dollars per share, and an other went from 100 to 105, the cheaper stock would have had a much larger relative change in value.

Comment: The file is almost 30 000 kB, and I have over 600 000 rows of data. Do you think I would get a better analysis if I looked at the percentage of the change? Namely, taking the difference between the stocks divided by the first value? And the one with the largest percentage change is the one to go with?

Comment: I think I solved the problem, thank you so much for the input, helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem/glad I could help. Good luck with your project